# GCC Preprocessor Output with Comments and Includes (but not expanded)

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

I'm looking for a way to generate preprocessed output that **contains comments and header includes**, *since I want to create a TypeInfo generator for **C** (The TypeInfo will be used to parse types and structures, for that it will be included and compiled with the project)*.
I know you can do that with:

```
gcc -E -CC -dI "file.c" -o "file.i"
```

- `-E` gets the preprocessed output
- `-CC` keeps all comments *(even from macro expansion)*
- `-dI` keeps includes *(`#include ..`)*

But it still pastes the contents of those includes (which will just be in my way), is there any way to remove those? If not is there a better preprocesser like GCC?

Comment: I can suppress **specific** headers by predefining their conditional translation macro, but they sometimes use `#pragma ones` and I would have to list all of them manually, which I'm afraid isn't generic enough for me... Also I'm afraid they might not be standardized...

Answer (score 1):

Just post-process the output, interpreting the [linemarkers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.2/cpp_9.html).

Example:

```
$ cat foo.c
#define quote(s)        #s
#include <fcntl.h>

quote(O_RDONLY) = O_RDONLY

$ cc -E -CC -dI -xc - < foo.c |
  perl -ne 'print unless /^# \d+ "(?!<stdin>")/../^# \d+ "<stdin>"/ or /^# \d+/'

#include <fcntl.h>


"O_RDONLY" =
                 00
```

Comment: I thought of that... but I'm afraid it'd add too much of extra time to the compilation process, since the TypeInfo output is used to compile the project. I will edit my question to mention that...